# Can sole member LLC add 1% partnership to deduct large business expenses?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, partnership

A sole member LLC has business expenses that can only be partially deducted from the individual's taxes because they far exceed the company's income.

The company changes to a partnership adding an individual but with only 1% interest.

The new partner contributes cash to the company to cover the business expense deficit and then deducts that same amount as a business expense from their new company from the taxes on their own existing income.

By diverting an amount that would have been paid to the IRS to their new company and then deducting that same amount, the overall transaction nets to zero but the company covers it's business expenses.

Can partners only deduct business expenses proportional to their interest in the company?

Even if they made an equivalent cash contribution to the company?

Can someone only deduct business expenses from taxes on income from that business only or all of their income regardless of the source?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing there and I'm not sure you are. Did a partnership acquire membership in the LLC? Did the LLC enter a general partnership with a natural person? Did a natural person join as an additional member to the LLC? Did the LLC disband and the member join a partnership with another?

Comment: Currently the company is a US sole member LLC. Taxes are filed on the individual's personal tax return. The idea is to change the individual's tax return from sole member LLC to partnership and then write in another individual as a partner. This individual would be chosen based on how much tax they anticipate paying. They would give that amount to the company to pay the business expenses. The new partner would then deduct the same amount from their taxes so that they are out-of-pocket nothing. They would receive something in return later as compensation for the burden of this process.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable because it is what Wolfgang Pauli calls "not even wrong".   It is all wishful/magical thinking with critical lack of actual facts about how this stuff works.  Might want to get a book on taxes, learn to fill out your own tax forms instead of leaving it to Turbotax, do a few "dry runs" on schedule C and D so you are comfortable with what is happening fiduciarily, and get a book or two on setting up businesses and see how the tax impacts work with each form. TLDR: lack of foundational knowledge, you have work to do.

Comment: "The new partner would then deduct the same amount from their taxes so that they are out-of-pocket nothing."  I don't see how.  Suppose your new partner is in a 30% marginal tax bracket.  They contribute $100,000 to the company.  Even if they can deduct that $100,000 from their taxable income, it will just reduce their tax liability by $30,000.  They are still out of pocket $70,000.  Deducting an expense doesn't make it vanish.

Comment: In fact, your "partner" could get exactly the same tax effect by just donating that $100,000 to charity.  They'd still be out of pocket $70,000, but at least they'd have the satisfaction of having helped out starving kittens or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

### Contributing cash to a company is not tax deductible

It’s either a capital contribution or a loan; either way it’s not an expense deductible to the individual (nor income to the company).

Answer (score 1):

@DaleM's answer is correct as far as it goes.

Neither loaning the company money, nor investing in it as an equity investment, is deductible.

> Can partners only deduct business expenses proportional to their
> interest in the company?

In an entity like an LLC taxed as a partnership, the allocation of items of income and expense in the company must have "substantial economic effect" which means that they must correspond to the economic reality of the company.

> Even if they made an equivalent cash contribution to the company?
>
> Can someone only deduct business expenses from taxes on income from
> that business only or all of their income regardless of the source?

In addition to the "substantial economic effect" rule there are several other limitations on taking losses.

One is the "at risk" rule which provides that you can't take more in losses from the venture than that maximum amount you could lose, which in an LLC would usually be your capital investment in the company.

Another is the "passive loss" rule which provides that a person who is not actively involved in a business may only use losses from passive activities to offset income from passive activities.

Yet another fairly newly enacted additional limitation is the [excess business loss limitation](https://www.becker.com/blog/accounting/theyre-back-2021-loss-limitations).

> The excess business loss limitation applies to noncorporate taxpayers
> and does not allow a loss that exceeds $262,000 (unmarried) or
> $524,000 (married) for 2021. The threshold amounts are adjusted
> annually for inflation. An excess loss not allowed in the current year
> is carried forward as a net operating loss. After a loss passes the
> hurdles of tax basis, at risk, and is not considered passive, the loss
> cannot exceed the excess business loss limitations.

And, if the business ceases to be profitable year after year (i.e. if it is not profitable for at least three of the last five tax years, unless it is a horse racing business), the [hobby loss rule](https://sharedeconomycpa.com/blog/irs-hobby-loss-rules) also disallowed net operating loss deductions from the LLC.

**Footnote**

The LLC could elect to be taxed as a C-corporation or an S-corporation, rather than under the default regime that applies to multiple member LLCs which is to be taxed as a partnership.

In an LLC taxed as a C-corporation entity level losses cannot be reported on shareholder tax returns. Federal income taxation takes place at the entity level, and shareholders are taxed only on actually distributed dividends and on capital gains from the sale of their stock.

In an LLC taxed as an S-corporation, a simplified variation on partnership style pass through taxation is used, but all items of income and expense must be allocated on a pro-rata basis. So, a 1% shareholder is allocated 1% of the company's net operating losses - subject also to the "at risk", "passive activity loss", and excess business loss limitations discussed above.

But, purchases of membership interests in LLCs and loans to LLCs that are taxed as C-corporations or as S-corporations are still not tax deductible.